# Redirections with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I need to rewrite the following URL:

```
http://XXXXXX.es/campusvirtual/moodle/login/index.php
```

Into this one:

```
http://YYYYYY.es/campusvirtual/login.php
```

Also when the user write the 2nd URL the browser lead to the 1st one.

I have this in my .htaccess and it does nothing:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXXXXX.es/(.+)\.php[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ YYYYYY.es/campusvirtual/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to literally only capture the case you've described, do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXXXXX.es$
RewriteRule campusvirtual/moodle/login/index.php http://YYYYYY.es/campusvirtual/login.php [L,R=301]
```

If you want to capture what's after `/moodle/` and before `index.php` for every request:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXXXXX.es$
RewriteRule campusvirtual/moodle/(.*)/index.php http://YYYYYY.es/campusvirtual/$1.php [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the below in .htaccess within campusvirtual folder:

```
# Redirect
Redirect /login.php http://xxxxxx.es/campusvirtual/moodle/login/index.php
```